# Openlayers ol-ext select multiple features to transform

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I am using the [ol-ext](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/) extension for Openlayers, which is awesome.

The piece I am interested in is the Transform interaction, I have it working inside a basic React example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/umrz7dd1/

This is the extent of the component so far:

```
class Select extends React.Component {
  static contextTypes = {map: PropTypes.object}
  componentDidMount() {
    this.select = new ol.interaction.Transform();
    this.context.map.addInteraction(this.select);
    console.log(this.select);
}
componentWillUnmount () {
  this.context.map.removeInteraction(this.select);
}
render() { return null; }
}
```

My question is, is there a way I can select multiple features at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Transform interaction is assumed to handle only one feature.
More than one could be used but I need use cases to see what's happened (should each feature rotate individualy? around which center? etc.).

You can ask for a enhancement on the [github page](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/issues).

Comment: That's a really valid point. I wanted to select multiple features so that I could get a cumulative area measurement. I have decided to go another direction, I have decided to have a 'transform' UI tools for the users and a seperate 'measure' tool. Accepting that answer as it is really informative.

Comment: Multi selection has been added to the last commit.

Comment: See http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html